# Stream builder snapshot.data!.docs not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, snapshot, stream-builder

I was trying to get data from firebase using stream builder in flutter and before it was working properly but now it could not find snapshots.data!.docs method pls help me

```
    StreamBuilder(
                    stream: database
                        .orderBy('datetime', descending: true)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return const Center(
                            child: Text('Error while fetching people'));
                      }

                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const SizedBox(
                          width: 0,
                          height: 0,
                        );
                      }

                      
                      var docs = snapshot.data!.docs; //error on this line it says that 
                                                      //The getter 'docs' isn't defined 
                                                     //for the type 'Object'.
                                        //Try importing the library that defines 'docs',
                                                // correcting the name to the name of an 
                           //existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'



                      return ListView.builder(
                        //controller: scrCntrlr,
                        itemCount: docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Card(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(docs[index]['from']),
                                ListTile(
                                  leading: (docs[index]['fromUserId'] != userId)
                                      ? const Icon(Icons.person)
                                      : const SizedBox(
                                          width: 0,
                                          height: 0,
                                        ),
                                  title: Text(docs[index]['msg']),
                                  subtitle: Text(docs[index]['time']),
                                  trailing:
                                      (docs[index]['fromUserId'] == userId)
                                          ? const Icon(Icons.person)
                                          : const SizedBox(
                                              width: 0,
                                              height: 0,
                                            ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    })
```

before it was working correctly but suddenly it says docs is not defined while trying to fetch data from firebase please help me

Comment: `StreamBuilder(
                    stream: database
                        .orderBy('datetime', descending: true)
                        .snapshots(),` DO NOT CREATE THE STREAM in the STREAM parameter of STREAMBUILDER: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: i did not understand could you help a bit more

Comment: I got the ans I just added <QuerySnapshot> on StreamBuilder like StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>() and it worked but thanks for trying to help mate